# CoreData How to send data to another View controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to implement feature in IOS where the user clicks on UIPickerController ie didSelectRow and that data is sent to another view controller

I am using IOS 10 , CoreData  here is a glimpse of how I am doing this.

```
// fetch data from the Core data model
   func fetchData(){
    // fetch the entity
    //1st stage:what is going to fetchgo and  fetch ProductDetails
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<ProductDetails>
         = ProductDetails.fetchRequest()
     // perform the above action :
    do {

          self.data = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for d in data {

            coursetitle = d.courseName!
            print("course title is: \(coursetitle)")

        }


          self.PickerCourse.reloadAllComponents()

    }
    catch {
        // handle any errors

        let error = error as NSError
        print("A Error has occurred while fetching data: \(error) !")

    }// end of catch statement


}// end of fetch data method
```

Above is my fetch data method that gets the data  from Core Data

I then load this into the UIPicker via my load method

// load data into the picker

```
func loadProductData(){

    if let item = productsToEdit {
        // can invoke relational ie toProductDetails
        if let store = item.toStore{

            var index = 0
            repeat{
                // populate in UIPicker 
                let sIndex = data[index]
                if sIndex.courseName == store.name
                {
                    PickerCourse.selectRow(index, 
                    inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                    break // out of the loop
                }
                index += 1 // increment index by 1

            }while (index < data.count)
        }

    }// end of item check

}// end of load product data
```

and here is the problem

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, 

  inComponent component: Int) {


    if component == 0{

        // what ever the row is selected assign the value to variable.
        CourseSelectedIndex = row
       productData = [data[row]]
        print("user has selected row at: \(productData)")
        //even if I include a segue here I get a error state Array can
        // not be assign to NSObject


    }


}
```

I hope above was more than enough information provided, your support in the correct direction would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you can pass data that are filled in array using row.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I solved my problem

not sure what the technical term is from my understanding 'Core Data' when creating a new information example  entity name table  attribute name

name = cat

The name will have its id this Id is known as objectId. You can fetch data by string match and other technique using the objectId. But if you want to pass information to multiple forms using the old fashion approach index values using arrays

then this should solve your problem

you first fetchdata from Core data and load it into array

```
var ArrayName: [String] = []

func fetchData(){

    print("you are outside the do loop fetch 
        method for debug purpose only ")

    do {

        data = try context.fetch(ProductDetails.fetchRequest())
        print("you are inside the do ...")

        for each in data {

            print("Course Name :  \(each.courseName!) 
             \n Price : \(each.price)\n \n Description: 
               \(each.desription) \n")


            ArrayName.append( each.Name!)// append to a array 
            print("You are in the Fetch method ...")

        }// end of for each


    }
    catch {
        // handle any errors


        print("What a nob you are indeed !")



    }// end of catch statement


}// end of fetch data method
```

of course you will need to store your array somewhere gobal so you can access it from any view controller

now you will need to load data into the UIPicker controller

// load data into the picker 
// create a NS object for core data 
    var productsToEdit: ProductDetails?
    func loadProductData(){

```
    if let item = productsToEdit {
        // can invoke relational ie toProductDetails
        if let store = item.toStore{

            var index = 0
            repeat{

                let sIndex = data[index]
                if sIndex.Name == store.name
                {
                    PickerCourse.selectRow(index, 
                     inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                    break // out of the loop
                }
                index += 1 // increment index by 1

            }while (index < data.count)
        }

    }// end of item check

}// end of load product data
```

insure you run these in view controll did load method in the following order

loadData()
fetchData()

also in your UIPicker controller ensure you have the following

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow 
row: Int,  forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


    return ArrayName[row]

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    // return number of rows within UIPickerView
    return data.count  
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    // return the number of  ' Colums to display

    return 1 
}



func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
 didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if component == 0{

        // what ever the row 
        is selected assign the value to variable.
        CourseSelectedIndex = row

        print("user has selected row at: \(productData)")

    }


}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



 }
```

Please bare in mind most of this code has been edit from my orignal code there some variable might show up as not declare etc...

If you found this useful please do give credit. and likewise correct me if I am wrong. we are here to learn.

thanks